# GPU detected with Tensorflow but not with Pytorch on a Macbook Pro M2

Tags: macos, pytorch, gpu, macbookpro

I try to find out why the GPU is recognized with :

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available() #I'm getting TRUE as output
```

and not with:

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available() #I'm getting False as output
```

my 'pip list' output command concerning Pytorch is :

```
torch                         2.0.1
torchaudio                    2.0.2
torchvision                   0.15.2
```

How can I fix Pytorch so as it can detect the GPU ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Mac with an M2 doesn't have a CUDA-capable GPU. However, you can use [MPS acceleration](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/mps.html):

```
torch.backends.mps.is_available() # True
device = torch.device("mps")
x = torch.tensor([1,2,3], device=device) # This will use MPS acceleration.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand better now. For my general knowledge, can we say that MPS acceleration provided by Apple is equivalent to NVIDIA GPus ?

Comment: It's similar, but some tensor operations (PyTorch functions) aren't supported yet, and it will be much slower than a high-end CUDA-capable GPU.